# java refresh JTable when query changed

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, h2

I'm building a SQL DB GUI. The problem I am having is when a user double clicks on a table from SHOW TABLES it doesn't update the table showing the new tables result.

This is my code:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
Statement stat = Gui.getStat();
private JPanel panel;
private String query;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    showTables();
}


public void showTables() throws SQLException{
        ResultSet showTablesResult = null;
        query = "abc";
        try {
            showTablesResult = stat.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error connecting to databse");
        }
        displayResultSet(showTablesResult);
    }


    public void displayResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{

        JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs)){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                   return false;
                }
        };

        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));


        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                if(e.getClickCount() == 2){
                    if(query == "abc"){
                        //get value in selected cell
                        String selectedData = null;
                        int[] selectedRow = table.getSelectedRows();
                        int[] selectedColumns = table.getSelectedColumns();

                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++) {
                          for (int j = 0; j < selectedColumns.length; j++) {
                            selectedData = (String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow[i], selectedColumns[j]);
                          }
                        }

                        try {
                            viewTable(selectedData);
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }



    public void viewTable(String tName) throws SQLException{
        ResultSet showTablesResult = null;
        query = "123";
        try {
            showTablesResult = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " +tName);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error connecting to databse");
        }
        displayResultSet(showTablesResult);
    }



    public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
            throws SQLException {

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }


        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    }
```

How can I fix this so that it works? I think there is probably a function that repaints or refreshes the table or something but I can't find what that is.

Thanks :)

Comment: Unrelated to your question: `query == "abc"` will not behave as expected. Use `"abc".equals( query )` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

By default components have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

When you add (or remove) components from a visible GUI you need to invoke the layout manager so a component is given a size/location on the panel. The basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

However, when using logic to "refresh" a table it is much easier to do:

```
table.setModel( your updated TableModel );
```

There is no need to recreate the JScrollPane and JTable every time.

Answer (score 0):

as camickr said, there is no need to recreate the JTable and the TableModel every time

I would do it like this:

Remove displayResultSet(...) from your viewTable(...) Method an just replace it with the following:

```
Vector<Vector<Object>> newDataVector = //fill with new data
defaultTableModel.setDataVector(newDataVector, columnIdentifiers);
defaultTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: You should NOT invoke the fireTableDataChanged() method manually. It is the responsibility of the TableModel to invoke the appropriate fireXXX(...) method.

Comment: I just looked in the sources: defaultTableModel.setDataVector(newDataVector, columnIdentifiers); will internally call fireTableStructureChanged(), so camickr is right, there is need to call fireTableDataChanged() by hand